# Django rest framework RecursionError during dispatch

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

From time to time, a `RecursionError` error gets triggered on my website. Unfortunately, the error log is not helpful.

One thing that strikes me as weird is that the `response = self.handle_exception(exc)` in the `except` is being called, but after that, the code continues from the line above at `response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)`

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    `.dispatch()` is pretty much the same as Django's regular dispatch,
    but with extra hooks for startup, finalize, and exception handling.
    """
    self.args = args
    self.kwargs = kwargs
    request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
    self.request = request
    self.headers = self.default_response_headers  # deprecate?

    try:
        self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)

        # Get the appropriate handler method
        if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
            handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(),
                              self.http_method_not_allowed)
        else:
            handler = self.http_method_not_allowed

        response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

    except Exception as exc:
        response = self.handle_exception(exc)

    self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
    return self.response
```

Should the code jump out of the `try` block when a exception occurs?

The traceback

```
Traceback:

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  116.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  495.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  492.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in list
  45.             return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  765.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  262.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  683.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in <listcomp>
  683.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  527.                 ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  514.                 attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in get_attribute
  454.             return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in get_attribute
  99.             if isinstance(instance, collections.Mapping):

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __instancecheck__
  193.             return cls.__subclasscheck__(subclass)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __subclasscheck__
  228.             if issubclass(subclass, scls):

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __subclasscheck__
  228.             if issubclass(subclass, scls):

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py" in __subclasscheck__
  1154.         return super().__subclasscheck__(cls)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __subclasscheck__
  209.         ok = cls.__subclasshook__(subclass)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py" in __extrahook__
  884.                 if issubclass(subclass, scls):

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __subclasscheck__
  228.             if issubclass(subclass, scls):

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py" in __subclasscheck__
  1154.         return super().__subclasscheck__(cls)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __subclasscheck__
  209.         ok = cls.__subclasshook__(subclass)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py" in __extrahook__
  884.                 if issubclass(subclass, scls):

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __subclasscheck__
  228.             if issubclass(subclass, scls):

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py" in __subclasscheck__
  1154.         return super().__subclasscheck__(cls)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __subclasscheck__
  209.         ok = cls.__subclasshook__(subclass)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py" in __extrahook__
  884.                 if issubclass(subclass, scls):

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __subclasscheck__
  228.             if issubclass(subclass, scls):

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py" in __subclasscheck__
  1154.         return super().__subclasscheck__(cls)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __subclasscheck__
  209.         ok = cls.__subclasshook__(subclass)
```

And it goes on for a few hundred lines then I have:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py" in __subclasscheck__
  1154.         return super().__subclasscheck__(cls)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __subclasscheck__
  209.         ok = cls.__subclasshook__(subclass)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py" in __extrahook__
  884.                 if issubclass(subclass, scls):

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __subclasscheck__
  222.         for rcls in cls._abc_registry:

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_weakrefset.py" in __iter__
  59.         with _IterationGuard(self):

During handling of the above exception (maximum recursion depth exceeded), another exception occurred:

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py" in __call__
  91.         response = response or self.get_response(request)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  36.             response = response_for_exception(request, exc)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in response_for_exception
  90.         response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in handle_uncaught_exception
  129.     return callback(request, **param_dict)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py" in server_error
  69.         template = loader.get_template(template_name)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  12.     engines = _engine_list(using)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in _engine_list
  66.     return engines.all() if using is None else [engines[using]]

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py" in all
  90.         return [self[alias] for alias in self]

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py" in __iter__
  87.         return iter(self.templates)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  37.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/path/to/webapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py" in templates
  54.         counts = Counter(backend_names)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py" in __init__
  535.         self.update(*args, **kwds)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py" in update
  614.             if isinstance(iterable, Mapping):

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __instancecheck__
  193.             return cls.__subclasscheck__(subclass)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __subclasscheck__
  228.             if issubclass(subclass, scls):

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __subclasscheck__
  228.             if issubclass(subclass, scls):

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py" in __subclasscheck__
  1154.         return super().__subclasscheck__(cls)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __subclasscheck__
  209.         ok = cls.__subclasshook__(subclass)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py" in __extrahook__
  884.                 if issubclass(subclass, scls):

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __subclasscheck__
  228.             if issubclass(subclass, scls):

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py" in __subclasscheck__
  1154.         return super().__subclasscheck__(cls)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py" in __subclasscheck__
```

This pattern repeats a few times over several thousand lines, until I receive a `maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` error

Comment: looks like you got a broken field class in your serializer

Comment: Can you be more precise? Also, this error only happens every once in a while, not every time the serializer is accessed.

Comment: @Linovia added more info, as there is actually a pattern in the log.